# Spark stateful computation: Create RDD within mappingFunction

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, rdd, stateful, bigdata

I am building a program using Spark Streaming which performs some linear regression on input data, predicts my output data and prints that prediction.

I also want to train my model on not only the incoming data but on the last xxx data points and I want to use  Sparks stateful computation capabilities for that task. My state keeps a list of data and, when the time comes, uses all that data to train the model and predict a new set of values.

The app is sent to a spark-dispatcher running on a mesos cluster using spark-submit which also sets the master url for the app. This seems to be the source for some problems as you see down below.

Sparks MLlib algorithms (LinearRegressionWithSGD) only accepts RDDs as input. That means I have to parallelize the data I keep in storage in my state, e.g. using something like (sc being the spark context):

```
    val parallelizedData = sc.parallelize(trainingData)
```

However, this yields a few problems:

- I can not provide my state with the spark context as it is not serializable and apparrently the state gets sent to all executers (I've tried that and I get a NotSerializableException)
- I tried to define an object that holds the spark context and use that directly in the class, the idea being that an object is a singleton and will be copied to the spark executor when the function needs it:

  ```
  object Spark {
   lazy val config = new SparkConf()
   lazy val context = new SparkContext
  }
  // Then in my state mapping fuction:
  val parallelizedData = Spark.context.parallelize(trainingData)
  ```

In this version the executor tries to create a new spark context but because the master URL is given via spark-submit and is not hard-coded, it does not work and I get the error "You must provide a master URL". This seems to be wrong, because obviously I don't want to (and can't) create a new context, but use the old one which already exists and is used in my main program long before I even try to train my model.

I also tried to set the master URL in the Spark-object above to be the master URL of the dispatcher but that does not work either. Hard-coding it to "local[N]" works, but then the app is not parallelized but only executed on the driver.

Does anyone have any experience with stateful computation in spark? There seems to be only very little documentation on the web, most of it is not applicable in my case. How can I send the context to the state? Or, how can I force the state to be executed on the driver so it has access to the state?

Or can I create an RDD that only resides on the worker and send that back to the driver which in turn aggregates the results and creates a new RDD that I can use for training?

Comment: I didn't have experience with stateful computations, but I know about new Spark 1.6 feature: mapWithState](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/01/faster-stateful-stream-processing-in-spark-streaming.html)
Hope this helps.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're actually trying to do. It seems odd to me that you need to store the `SparkContext` inside an object. Try describing what your intentions are, and what you're trying to achieve instead.